# signedness of plain `int` bitfield

Tags: c, bit-fields

The C standard in 6.7.2/5 says:

> ... it is
> implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the
> same type as `unsigned int`.

The [`x86-64` ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) specifies in 3.1.2:

> Bit-fields that are neither signed nor unsigned always have non-negative values. Although they may have type `char`, `short`, `int`, or `long` (which can have negative values), these bit-fields have the same range as a bit-field of the same size
> with the corresponding unsigned type.

Therefore, in the following program, I would expect the assertion to pass (at least on Linux).

```c
#include <assert.h>

struct S {
  int x : 3;
};

struct S s;
int main() {
  s.x = 6;
  assert(s.x == 6);
}
```

But it fails both in Clang and in Gcc. Why?

Furthermore, Clang emits a warning:

```
warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to bit-field changes value from 6 to -2
```

So it behaves as if the bit-field was declared `signed int`. If I make it explicitly `unsigned int`, the warning disappears and the assertion passes.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is documented in the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html):

> > Whether a “plain” int bit-field is treated as a signed int bit-field or as an unsigned int bit-field (C90 6.5.2, C90 6.5.2.1, C99 and C11 6.7.2, C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).
>
> By default it is treated as signed int but this may be changed by the -funsigned-bitfields option.